# How to provide more up-to-date versions of existing Ubuntu software for a lower version?

Tags: ppa, packaging

Concretely, I'd like to provide a version of `add-apt-repository` with the `--enable-sources` option for Ubuntu 12.04 which is used by the travis-ci.org CI service, but I'm looking for a generic solution. I figured it'd be easy to provide them through a PPA, but I don't find a good guide how to repackage software which already is debian software.

Afaik, the first relevant command in case the source root retrieved with `apt-get source` already is `bzr builddeb -- -S -us -uc` which fails due to `bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/afs/richtercloud.de/sources/software-properties-0.96.24.7/".` for `software-properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are dealing with `debian source package` not `bazaar source repository`, did you get the idea?

The work-flow is quite different. I can't resume every thing here, it is a vast topic. Here some points to show you a quick one of many ways out there.

1. Check which package

   ```
   $ which apt-add-repository 
   /usr/bin/apt-add-repository

   $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/apt-add-repository
   software-properties-common: /usr/bin/apt-add-repository
   ```
2. Download the source

   ```
   apt-get source software-properties-common
   ```
3. Install build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep software-properties-common
   ```
4. Build source package

   ```
   $ cd software-properties-*/
   $ dch

   software-properties (0.96.20ubuntu1~trusty) trusty; urgency=medium

     * Backport to trusty

    -- First Last <username@gmail.com>  Sun, 20 Nov 2016 18:43:42 +0100

   $ cd ../software-properties-*/
   $ debuild -S

   $ ls ..
   ```
5. Upload to PPA

   ```
   dput yourppa ../software-properties_0.96.20ubuntu1~trusty_source.changes
   ```